# Best strategy to create a ListView of forms in Android?

Tags: android, forms, list, listview, fragment

I need to create a dynamic list of forms. The user would be able to input data into each element of the list (which would contain an editable text box and other elements).

What is the best approach? How would I access the inputted information in each list element? Would each list element have to be its own Fragment?

Answer (score 0):

```
1) Decide what elements you need in each list item
2) Create a data class with the member variables to how your data. one data object will be initialized per listview item //note this is not required, but it can help. 
3) Create a layout (list_view_item_layout.xml) for your listview items
4) Declare your ListView in your layout.xml, ensure that you give it an android:id.
5) Declare and initialize an array of your data objects (or just an array of data) that holds all the data objects that you want displayed in your list 
5) Create your MyListViewAdapter.class that extends BaseAdapter. this class will inflate your list_view_item_layout and populate the views with the data that is in your data array
6) call ListView#setAdapter(); passing in myListViewAdfapter, context, R.id.document_list_view //I htink that is correct
```

Thats about all there is to it.
Look  for tutorials for custom list view adapters, there are a billion + tutorials